# Unterschied zwischen "deshalb" und "deswegen"

Tags: difference, meaning

Welchen Unterschied gibt es zwischen den beiden Wörtern *deshalb* und *deswegen*?

Im Duden wird *deswegen* lediglich mit *deshalb* erklärt:

http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/deswegen

Comment: @Close voters: Ich meine, wir hätten uns auf Meta darauf geeinigt, Fragen, die nach dem gleichen fragen, aber das **auf verschiedenen Sprachen** tun, offenzulassen (und mit querverbindenden Links zu versehen).

Comment: @Jan: Nur, wenn der Fragende das Duplikat nicht versteht. Hier hat der Fragende das Duplikat selbst als solches akzeptiert (deswegen ist *Community* unter den Schließenden), insofern liegt kein Problem vor.